# NPOI Autosize Columns (SXSSFWorkbook)

Tags: vb.net, npoi

OK, so I'm using version 2.3.0 of the NPOI.
My Workbook is SXSSFWorkbook format.

I'm trying to autosize the columns...but I can't figure out how to use the NEW Autosize Tracker.

Can anyone figure this out?
It was a bug fix, here is the web site...but there aren't any examples on how to get it to work, should I be using a different version of NPOI?

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57450

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using  NPOI 2.2.1 version .  if you are looking for auto sizing a column, below code and approach I am using for XSSF workbook.

```
 XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("Template");
 sheet.AutoSizeColumn(yourColumnIndex);
```

Comment: That doesn't work when the worksheet using Streaming (SXSSF) Workbook format.